# Is there a way to use a prop as the site-key for vue-recaptcha?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-recaptcha

I have a Form component in Vue where I import the vue-recaptcha like this:

```
<template>
   ... Contains the form and button that triggers onSubmit function
</template>

<script>
    import { VueReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3';

    Vue.use(VueReCaptcha, {
        siteKey: "hard-coded site-key here",
        loaderOptions: {
             useRecaptchaNet: true,
        },
    });

    export default {
        methods: {
            async onSubmit(e) {
                // Uses the recapatcha and handles errors/success etc.
            },
        },
    };

    ...
```

This works since the value for site-key is hard-coded.

However, I wish to be able to pass the site-key as a prop to the Form component and then use this as the site-key.

I tried something as bold as simply creating a prop in the Form component and passing it in as the site-key when setting the vue-recaptcha options, like this:

```
<script>

   import { VueReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3';

   Vue.use(VueReCaptcha, {
       siteKey: this.siteKey,
       loaderOptions: {
            useRecaptchaNet: true,
       },
   });

export default {
        props: {
            siteKey: String,
        },

        ...

</script>
```

This does not work because `this.siteKey` is undefined, as expected. However, is there a way to set the site-key value as the prop `siteKey`? Maybe there is a way to set the vue-recaptcha plugin options inside the component where `this.siteKey` isn't undefined, for example in `mounted()`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to provide the Key to the Form over prop?

```
 <my-form siteKey="<My Site Key>" ...
```

or

```
 <my-form site-key="<My Site Key>" ...
```

Pay attention:

> You should be careful with components and prop's naming & using, since there are [DOM
> Template Parsing Caveats](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats)